# HERE Search API always returns 0 images

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to get nearby restaurants using the HERE Places API (discover/search) in which the data is great however when I get the json response of returned restaurants and then get the place detail, the json response from that always contains 0 images on the media attribute.

I'm happy to use any HERE API call however I need a list of places (restaurants) with images (links to images) in the response.

```
media: {
   images: {
      available:0
      items: [ ]
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media section in a place details response returns different kinds of media collections, such as editorials, reviews, and images relevant for a particular place. Hence if the place has relevant image, then it will show content rich data

These media come with source attribution in the attribution field. Clients that show media content are obliged to show the content of the attribution field next to the media content. For more information, see Source Attributions.

> **Note: Some of the content that could be potentially included in responses come from external providers. Due to contractual reasons,
>   not all content is available to all clients.**

For more details please refer :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/rich-content.html